# homeomorphism in $(-\infty,-1) ∪ [0,\infty)$ of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let X be the subspace $(-∞, -1) ∪ [0, ∞)$  of $\mathbb{R}$. We define $f∶ X → \mathbb{R}$ as

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+1 & \text{ if } x< -1 \\ 
x & \text{ if } x\geq 0
\end{cases}$

Prove that f is bijective, preserves order, and is continuous. Is it f a
homeomorphism?

Now, I'm a little confused by the concept of "piecewise-continuous" I mean my function f is continuous in $(-∞, -1) ∪ [0, ∞)$, or not? :c
I appreciate any help

Comment: It is continuous. The only point at which that might not be immediately pretty clear is $0$, and it’s not hard to check that if $(a,b)$ is an open interval containing $0$, then $f^{-1}[(a,b)]$ is an open set in $X$.

Comment: $f$ is not a homeomorphism because $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $0$. This is easy to see once you compute $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you <3

Comment: @davidhernandez: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is continuous: $f^{-1}[(a,b)] = (a,b)$ when $0 < a < b$ and $f^{-1}[[(a,b)] = (a-1,b-1)$ when $a < b <0$ while $f^{-1}[(-a,a)] = (-a-1,-1) \cup [0,a)$ which is open in $X$ (as it equals $(-a-1,a) \cap X$). These $3$ types of open intervals form a base for $\Bbb R$ (to take care of the special role of $0$ here).

$g:=f^{-1}$ is not continuous: in $\Bbb R$, $-\frac1n \to 0$ while $g(-\frac1n) = -1 - \frac1n$ does not converge to $g(0) = 0$ in $X$ (in the subspace topology:  $[0,\frac12)$ is open in $X$ but contains no points of $(g(-\frac1n))_n$).

$g$ *would* be continuous if $X$ had the order topology wrt the inherited order, though.. Here is an example where the subspace topology on $X$ differs from it.

Comment: Thanks I got it